# RStudio/RMD files to create a student version assignment from the instruction version assignment solution

Tags: r, rstudio

Does anyone know plugin or package in Rstudio to create a student version assignment from the instruction version assignment solution?

I know nbgrader for Jupyter Notebook that can do this, but I am working on RMD files in RStudio.

Answer (score 2):

How about [learnr](https://rstudio.github.io/learnr/)?

Here is the link to the package information:
https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/learnr/index.html

Comment: I have to share with students the version of RMD that does not include solutions.

Comment: Pretty sure `learnr` does just that, no? @osmjit

Comment: I have never used it. if someone can give a starter example that would help

Comment: That first link is a tutorial on how to use it, with examples. I have never used it myself, was just trying to help.